# Run secure command-line via https using sshd and corkscrew

Tags: ssh

Will corkscrew let me run command-line programs on my remote servers?

EG, I want "https://user@cmd.barrycarter.info/date/+%Y/" to prompt me 
for a 401-style password (ie, my standard login password), and then 
return an HTTP page with just "2011" on it.

I've been reading about sshd's ProxyCommand, but am not sure I 
understand it.

General whining:

- I'm often at a client's and need ssh access to my server. Some of 
  my clients can/will/have installed putty, but many haven't and 
  won't. They don't have a problem with my visiting webpages (I can't 
  convince them that installing putty is much safer than visiting 
  certain webpages).
- From home, I use SSH keys to access my machine, but still allow 
  the username/password authentication method.
- I realize this seems really insecure, although it's probably no 
  less secure than running ssh from the command line using 
  username/password.
- I realize I could write a CGI that does all this, but am wondering 
  if there's an existing solution. Plus, I'd like to run the "ssh web 
  server" on its own port with nothing else + don't want to fire up 
  two copies of lighttpd (assuming that's even possible).

Answer (score 0):

As you've described it, I think your problem would need you to write a custom CGI.

Maybe you could use [portaputty](http://code.google.com/p/portaputty/) instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, clients aren't always comfortable with my plugging USB drives into their machines, either. They usually become comfortable later, but I often need ssh access early in the process.

Comment: Sheesh... then maybe they'd be okay with you downloading portaputty and running it?  You'd have to reenter your session details each time, but that's not too bad.

Comment: At first, my clients really don't want me putting anything on their machine at all. Maybe I should say "prospective clients". Once they hire me, they're OK w/ my doing stuff (because that's what they pay me for)